# Python py2exe [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'glew32.dll'

Tags: python, kivy, py2exe

I am attempting to create an exe with py2exe and I am receiving an error.

No such file or directory: 'glew32.dll'.

My console output.
[image: console output]

I already have the file installed

[image]

I have attempted to troubleshoot by adding a glew to my path.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Using-Kivy-with-an-existing-Python-installation-on-Windows-(64-or-32-bit)

Read through that and you should be fine it's somewhat older info but it's still very relevant. For the love of god remove that from your path it won't help.